# Use Windows Powershell to subtract numeric values from 2 csv files and product an output file showing an additional variance column

Tags: powershell

I have 2 csv files with data values against certain parameters as below

File1

```
Entity Account Amount
100    1001    $100
100    1004    $300
101    1002    $200
```

File2

```
Entity Account Amount
100    1001    $100
100    1004    $200
101    1002    $200
101    1005    $500
```

Using above 2 files, i need to produce another csv file which has amount columns as per file 1 and file 2 and also a variance column showing difference in 2 files as below

Output File

```
Entity Account Amount as per file1  Amount as per file2 Variance Amount
100    1001    $100                  $100                 0 
100    1004    $300                  $200                 $100
101    1002    $200                  $200                 0  
101    1005    $0  (blank record)    $500                 ($500)
```

I know that we have compare object command and we can find unique/diff records b/w 2 csv files using same and I did it successfully. However please let me know if we can merge the files and produce a variance file as above through powershell

I am new to scripting so any pointers will be helpful

I tried compare-object as below to fetch unique records from 2 files

```
PS C:\Users\Daman>  compare-object (Get-Content C:\File1.csv) (Get-Content C:\File2.csv)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no join (nor left outer join) in PS so it is just better to use for loops.  See code below :

```
$filename1 = "c:\temp\test.csv"
$filename2 = "c:\temp\test1.csv"

$temp = Import-CSV -Path $filename1
#make $temp expandable
#$csv1 = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
$csv1 = [System.Collections.ArrayList]$temp
$csv2 = Import-CSV -Path $filename2

#add column to $csv2 to indicate a match, rows with not match gets added later
foreach($row2 in $csv2)
{
   $row2 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Found -NotePropertyValue $False
}
#add csv2 to csv1
foreach($row1 in $csv1)
{
   foreach($row2 in $csv2)
   {
      if(($row1.Entity -eq $row2.Entity) -and ($row1.Account -eq $row2.Account))
      {
         $row1 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Amount2 -NotePropertyValue $row2.Amount
         $row2.Found = $True
         break;
      } 
   }
}
#add rows that are only in $csv2 to $csv1
foreach($row2 in $csv2)
{
   if(-not $row2.Found)
   {
         $newRow = New-Object -TypeName psobject
         $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Entity -NotePropertyValue $row2.Entity
         $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Account -NotePropertyValue $row2.Account
         $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Amount2 -NotePropertyValue $row2.Amount
         $csv1.Add($newRow)  | Out-Null
   }
}
foreach($row1 in $csv1)
{
   $amount1 = 0;
   if($row1.Amount -ne $null)
   {
      $amount1 = [int]$row1.Amount.Substring(1)
   }
   $amount2 = 0;
   if($row1.Amount2 -ne $null)
   {
      $amount2 = [int]$row1.Amount2.Substring(1)
   }
   $variance = $amount1 - $amount2
   if($variance -lt 0)
   {
      $row1 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Variance -NotePropertyValue ('($' + [Math]::abs($variance) + ')')
   }
   else
   {
      $row1 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Variance -NotePropertyValue ('$' + $variance)
   }
}
$csv1 | Format-Table
```

Results

```
Entity Account Amount Amount2 Variance
------ ------- ------ ------- --------
100    1001    $100   $100    $0
100    1004    $300   $200    $100
101    1002    $200   $200    $0
101    1005           $500    ($500)
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your help. However some how we are unable to fetch the report in tabular format and somehow the Format-Table command seems to be not giving the expected result in tabular form as above.

Comment: Input data may not be CSV.  Instead fixed width data with columns separated by spaces.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Further to this, is there a way we can remove  $0 Variance  rows from output variance file and keep only rows with variance

Comment: $csv1 | Where-Object {$_.Variance -ne '$0'} | export-csv -path 'filename'

Comment: Thanks so much for your inputs. It works fine but we have an issue whereby amounts are too small and it doesnot recognize the same. Like if the amount is -0.000000031, it is reading the same as -3.10E-08. Can we add something so it reads this value as 0 only without any decimals.

Comment: Powershell is written in c# and you can use any c# method.  There is a Match library with Round and Truncate which you can use.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.truncate?view=net-7.0  So you can use [System.math]::Round($variance,2)